# A question of divisibility.

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Let $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime integers.

Consider $S = \{\frac{p}{q}\} + \{\frac{2p}{q}\} + \{\frac{(q-1)p}{q}\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of the real number $x$.

Prove that $2S$ is divisible by $(q-1)$.

I could not do much with it. May be a very easy problem but I could not do it. $S$ is a fraction, may not a natural number. But $2S$ is an integer and divisible by $(q-1)$, an integer. How ?

Comment: Shouldn't the sum in $S$ go over all multiples of $p$ from $1$ to $q-1$ in the numerators?

Comment: This is not mentioned in the problem.

Comment: First of all, the last term seems to have a typo. It should be $q$ in the denominator.

Comment: The claim is obviously not correct the way stated. Take $p=1$ and $q=5$ for instance. $S=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{4}{5}=\frac{7}{5}$.

Comment: So the problem is wrongly written at the page from where I have copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^{q-1} \{ \frac{ip}{q} \}$.
Since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, multiplication by $p$ permutes the nonzero residues mod $q$, and so 
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^{q-1} \{ \frac{ip}{q} \}
= \sum_{i=1}^{q-1} \{ \frac{i}{q} \}
= \frac 1q \sum_{i=1}^{q-1} i
= \frac 1q \cdot \frac{q(q-1)}{2} 
= \frac{q-1}{2} .
$$

Comment: Can you explain a little. I am not getting the step $\sum_{i = 1}^{q-1}\{\frac{ip}{q}\} =  \sum_{i = 1}^{q-1}\{\frac{i}{q}\}$

Comment: @Dane +1 Elegant!

Comment: @Dutta Since $p$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $q$ the mapping $i\in\lbrace 1,2,\dotsc,q-1\rbrace \mapsto (pi)_{\mod q}$ is a bijection.

Comment: I am not much familiar to algebra. What is $(pi)_{modq}$

Comment: @Dutta The basic observation is that adding fractions $i/q + j/q$ and taking fractional parts is really the same as adding $i+j$ and then taking the remainder when dividing by $q$. This is called [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: $S = \{\frac{p}{q}\} + \{\frac{2p}{q}\} + \{\frac{(q-1)p}{q}\} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{q-1} (\frac{jp}{q}-[\frac{jp}{q}])$

$2S=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{q-1} (\frac{jp}{q}+\frac{(q-j)p}{q})+2\sum\limits_{j=1}^{q-1} ([\frac{jp}{q}])=p(q-1)-2N$, where $N$ is the number of lattice points under the line $y=\frac{p}{q}x$ between $x=1$ to $x=q-1$. Since, $gcd(p,q)=1$, the number of lattice points on the line $y=\frac{p}{q}x$ between $x=1$ to $x=q-1$ is $0$ (why ??).

So, $2N=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{q-1} ([\frac{jp}{q}]+[\frac{(q-j)p}{q}])$ gives the number of lattice points in the box $x=1$ to $x=q-1$ and $y=1$ to $y=p-1$; that is $(p-1)(q-1)$.

Therefore, $2S=p(q-1)-(p-1)(q-1)=q-1$.